# Infinity is Many-One

Tags: infinity, philosophy

Bertrand Russell in Introduction to mathematical philosophy states, "It will be observed that zero and infinity, alone among ratios, are not one-one. Zero is one-many, and infinity is many-one." (P.40)

I think I understand that zero is one-many because I can take zero divided by any non-zero number and the conclusion is the same. I don't understand that when he says "infinity is many-one"

Comment: Infinity is the sum of many ones, right?

Comment: I don't know...can it be defined that way? That seems to imply that I can sum finite numbers and reach something infinite?

Comment: try simply 1/x and realize what happens to one-many under inversion, or check out the real protective plain. both are unique solutions to xy=x which is essentially what breaks the division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the full discusssion in [**CH:VII RATIONAL, REAL, AND COMPLEX NUMBERS**](https://books.google.it/books?id=jF1j0y2-hM0C&pg=PA65); he is defining *fractions* :

> We shall define the *fraction* $\dfrac m n$ as being that relation which holds between two inductive numbers [see page 27 : We shall use the phrase “inductive numbers” to mean thesame set as we have hitherto spoken of as the “*natural numbers*.”] $x, y$ when $xn = ym$. This definition enables us to prove that $\dfrac m n$ is a one-one relation, provided neither $m$ nor $n$ is zero.
>
> It will be seen that $\dfrac 0 n$ is always the same relation, whatever inductive number $n$ may be; it is, in short, the relation of $0$ to any other inductive cardinal. [Thus :] Zero is *one-many*.
>
> Conversely, the relation $\dfrac m 0$ is always the same, whatever inductive number $m$ may be. There is not any inductive cardinal to correspond to $\dfrac m 0$. We may call it “the infinity of rationals.” It is an instance of the
> sort of infinite that is traditional in mathematics, and that is represented by “$\infty$.” [Thus:] infinity is *many-one*.

In other words, if we agree to "name" with the symbol “$\infty$” the relation $\dfrac m 0$, this holds for any $m$.

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful:)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Real interval $[0,\epsilon]$. How many points are inside that interval? Divide the interval so that the new interval is $[0,\epsilon/2] $. How many points are inside this interval? Still infinitely many. We say that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ in the language of Real Analysis. This means you can always find rational numbers in a neighbourhood of a real number (loosely speaking). In fact, you can always find infinitely many rational numbers inside an  arbitrarily small (non zero) real interval

Comment: or better yet call the first interval the one, go one to one back to the original interval and end with many without changing the ratio.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...I am sure that you have explained this sufficiently...unfortunately I don't quite understand...perhaps you could refer me to something that would help me understand your answer better...again thank you for the conversation ...always helpful :)

Comment: Look at a ruler. The space between the 0 and the 10 is similar to the space between the 0 and the 1. That space is also similar to the space between the 0 and 100 (if you have a metre stick). That's the point really. You can keep dividing the interval up and always get infinitely many points inside the new interval. What's the smallest unit of measure? You can't find one. (Well, it's the infinitesimal element we call dS)

Comment: Thank you Anthony for the clarification on your answer. The last part that is confusing for me is what we are saying as many? Many points? Many what? And one number to represent this (ie infinity)?

Comment: Yeah so if you take all the numbers between 0 and 1 (all the decimal numbers), there are infinitely many of them. Remove one of them, say 0.5. How many are there left? Still infinitely many.